# Task Runner Explorer does not group the tasks in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gulp, visual-studio-2015

It seems that the grouping of tasks does not work in `VS 2015` vs a "correct" behavior in VS 2013 with the installed "Task Runner Explorer" plug-in...

[image: the grouping in VS 2015 does not seem to correctly work]

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='default' />
///
// include plug-ins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var del = require('del');


var config = {
    //JavaScript files that will be combined into a jquery bundle
    jquerysrc: [
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js'
    ],
    jquerybundle: 'Scripts/jquery-bundle.min.js'
}

// Synchronously delete the output script file(s)
gulp.task('clean-vendor-scripts', function (cb) {
    return del([config.jquerybundle], cb);
});

//Create a jquery bundled file
gulp.task('jquery-bundle', ['clean-vendor-scripts'], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.jquerysrc)
     .pipe(concat('jquery-bundle.min.js'))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts'));
});

//Set a default tasks
gulp.task('default', ['jquery-bundle'], function () {    
});
```

Is there a way to fix it?